# Stochastic Calc

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-differential-equations

(a) Consider the process
$$
\mathrm d\sqrt{v} = (\alpha - \beta\sqrt{v})\mathrm dt + \delta \mathrm dW
$$
Here $\alpha, \beta,$ and $\delta$ are constants. Using Ito's Lemma show that 
$$
\mathrm dv = (\delta^2 + 2\alpha\sqrt{v} - 2\beta v)\mathrm dt + 2\delta\sqrt{v}\mathrm dW.
$$

(b) Using Ito's Lemma to find the SDE satisfied by $U$ given that $U =\ln(Y)$ and $Y$ satisfies
$$
\mathrm dY = \frac{1}{2Y}\mathrm dt + \mathrm dW \\
Y(0) = Y_0.
$$

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Looks like the image got blown away. It helps to format your questions using [*MathJax*](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). Regards

Comment: Did you delete the last line of your post that had a number and a link? That was necessary syntax for the image to show up.

Comment: I tried to upload an image of the question which is written in a pdf document but as I am a new member the website wouldn't allow me to do so. Instead I have typed the question above as best as I could.

Comment: I have posted the question as an image. Please click on the link to view the question.

Comment: @Mike: Please for future questions do *not* just post a link to a picture containing the question. Please type up the question and format it using MathJax (LaTeX). You can see more about how to do that here: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference I typed up this question for you.

Comment: @Mike: Please for future questions do not just post your homework without any personal input, this makes difficult to adjust the level of the answer (and, at least to some users, is not an incentive to answer).

Answer (score 1):

(a)  Notice that $v = f(\sqrt{v})$ for $f(x)=x^2$. We have $f'(x)=2x$ and $f''(x)=2$.

Ito's lemma yields:
$$
dv = f'(\sqrt{v})\,d\sqrt{v} + \frac{1}{2}f''(\sqrt{v})\,d\langle\sqrt{v}\rangle.
$$

Hence
\begin{align}
dv &= 2\sqrt{v}\times\left((\alpha-\beta\sqrt{v})\,dt + \delta \,dW\right) + \frac{1}{2}\times 2\times\delta^2\,dt\\
&=(\delta^2 + 2\alpha\sqrt{v} - 2\beta v)\,dt + 2\delta \sqrt{v}\, dW.
\end{align}

---

(b)  Take $f(y)=\ln y$. We have $f'(y)=\dfrac{1}{y}$ and $f''(y)=-\dfrac{1}{y^2}$. Hence $U(0)=\ln Y(0)$ and
\begin{align}
dU &= df(Y) = \frac{1}{Y}\left(\frac{1}{2Y}dt+dW\right) - \frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{Y^2}dt\\
& = \frac{1}{Y}dW\\
& = e^{-U}dW
\end{align}

Comment: Hi Ju'x thanks for explaining the calculation to reach the solution